# Aquamacs Preview doesn't work

Tags: preview, aquamacs

I've been using `aquamacs` 2.4 on my osx 10.7.5. After it crashed with my font change operation, the preview menu bar disappeared and doen't appear again after rerunning the program. Although I reinstalled the `aquamacs` package, the problem was not fixed. Could anybody help me on this problem?

Comment: Is AUCTeX still loaded on your emacs?  (I believe both are pre-packaged with Aquamacs nowadays, but I can't be sure since I'm a GNU Guy.  AUCTeX and `preview` are closely intertwined.)  Also, could you elaborate on this 'font change operation'?  Which fonts were you changing?

Comment: Try renaming the "Aquamacs Emacs" folder in `~/Library/Preferences/` so as to start in a fresh state.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the `.emacs` file in my home directory. I put below contents, which I copy and pasted, to enable spell checking function. Once I remove the contents, the `preview` function turn on. But I'm still not aware of why following made the problem. Thank you for all in this thread.

```
(setq ispell-program-name "aspell") ; could be ispell as well, depending on your preferences

(setq ispell-dictionary "english") ; this can obviously be set to any language your spell-checking program supports

(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'flyspell-mode)

(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'flyspell-buffer)
```